# How to choose the target forwarding address?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

SSH the Definite Guide says

> Suppose you want to forward a connection from your local machine to
>   remote.host.net. Both of the following commands work:
>
> ```
> $ ssh -L2001:localhost:143 remote.host.net
> $ ssh -L2001:remote.host.net:143 remote.host.net
> ```
>
> **The forwarded connection is made from the remote machine to either the
>   loopback address or remote.host.net**, and in either case, the
>   connection stays on the remote machine and doesn’t go over the
>   network. However, the two connections are perceptibly different to the
>   server receiving the forwarded connection. This is because **the source
>   sockets of the connections are different**. The connection to localhost
>   appears to come from **source address 127.0.0.1**, whereas the connection
>   to remote.host.net is from **the address associated with that name**.

What is "the address associated with that name"?

How is it different from "source address 127.0.0.1"?

Thanks.

Comment: that's a lousy description; when `ssh` is using the `-L lport:rhost:rport` option and receives a connection request of `lport`, it's the `ssh` on the remove machine which does the lookup for `rhost`, and there `remote.host.net` could be configured to return the same ip address as `localhost`, or none at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore `ssh` for the moment, and do something more simple.

If you do

```
telnet localhost 143
```

then the connection is made from `localhost` to `localhost`

If, instead, you do

```
telnet my.ip.address 143
```

then the connection is made from `my.ip.address` to `my.ip.address`

In both cases we're connecting to port 143 on the same machine, but the source address changes.  So we can see that the target IP address changes the source IP address.

The same is true for `ssh` port forwarding.

With the first version you are making a connect to `localhost` and so the source is `localhost`.  With the second version you are making a connection to the server's main IP address (remote.host.net's IP address), and so the source is from that IP address.

This isn't an `ssh` specific issue; it's how IP routing typically works.